# Cannot load JAR file as resource in JBoss 7.1

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, classloader, jboss7.x

I need to load a JAR file as a resource, say X.JAR, located within the LIB directory of an EAR, where the call to load originates from a class within the jar file.

I understand this is a very weird thing to do, but that's just the way it is with old code.

I have tried this:

```
getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
```

and the getResource() tricks but they all return a location that does not physically exist. I use the management console of JBoss to deploy the EAR file, I do not place it exploded into the deployment folder -- unfortunately this step cannot be changed.

Comment: this.getClass().getResource("").getPath(); - returned the same path as the protection domain thing

Comment: Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("/lib/X.jar") - returns null

Comment: .class.getClassLoader().getResource("/lib/X.jar") - returns null as well

Comment: Your best bet might be to set a system property containing a path directly pointing to the JAR... not nice but works.

Comment: hmmm. i'll leave that as a last gasp alternative. it introduces complications on the client end.

Answer (score 1):

A solution can be put your jar inside another jar, then it is a file in the classpath and you can load it via getResource method.

BTW, can you post the full line of the getResource() you have tried?

Try to use .getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()

Comment: interesting, but that would mess up a lot of things. I just finished wrestling with the module/classloader of JBoss 7, don't want to go through it again.

Comment: Try to use .getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()

Answer (score 0):

You should put the jar name in     MANIFEST.MF, something like

```
Class-Path:yourjar.jar        
Dependencies:com.blah.blah
```